# Reading values from file and storing them in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to write a function read_file() to read the values in the file and store the data in the a dictionary. The dictionary will look something like this:

```
product = {'d01':['pencil', 5], 'd02':['highlighter', 7], 'd03':['sharpener', 10]....}
```

What the items in the file looks like:

input:

```
d={}
file=r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Folder\products.dat"
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for items in f:
       print(items)
```

results:

```
d01,pencil,5
d02,highlighter,7
d03,sharpener, 10
d04,pen,3
```

Here are my codes:

```
def read_file():
 d={}
 file=r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Folder\products.dat"
 with open(file,'r') as f:
    for items in f:
       stuff = items.split(",")
       quantity = int(stuff[2].rstrip())
       a = stuff[0]
       b = [stuff[1], quantity]
       d = {a:b}
       print(d)
read_file()
```

Currently results I got:

```
{'d01': ['pencil', 5]}
{'d02': ['highlighter', 7]}
{'d03': ['sharpener', 10]}
{'d04': ['pen', 3]}
```

How do I achieve the above results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a new dictionary for each line, add an element to the same dictonary.

Change

```
d = {a:b}
```

to

```
d[a] = b
```

And put `print(d)` after the loop is done, not inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To read and parse a csv file into a dictionary of lists, using the first item on each line as a key and the remaining items on each line as a value list:

```
import csv
def parse(csvfilename):
    dic = {}
    with open(csvfilename, "r") as csvfile
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in csvreader:
            table[row[0]] = row[1:]
    return dic
```

[image]